# Getting time outs while deleting the files from Microsoft azure

Tags: c#, .net, linq, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to delete the backup files (which are older than 30 days) from Microsoft azure using C# code but unfortunately i'm getting time out issues ,For error message please click the below "Error code".Can any one please help me on that.

[image: Error code]

Please see the code below:

[image: Code]

Comment: How big are the files?

Comment: Please show your code (as text, not a screenshot)

Comment: Please paste the text, not an image. And I do not see anything related to timeouts?

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that.

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

If you could locate this issue and confirm that the error is thrown at `container.ListBlobs`, I assume that you could set [BlobRequestOptions.ServerTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.servertimeout.aspx) to improve the server timeout for your request. Also, you could leverage [BlobRequestOptions.RetryPolicy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.retrypolicy.aspx) ([LinearRetry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.retrypolicies.linearretry.aspx) or [ExponentialRetry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.retrypolicies.exponentialretry.aspx)) to enable retries when a request failed. Here is the code snippet, you could refer to it:

```
container.ListBlobs(null, false, options: new BlobRequestOptions()
{
    ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
});
```

or

```
container.ListBlobs(null, false, options: new BlobRequestOptions()
{   
    //the server timeout interval for the request
    ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    //the maximum execution time across all potential retries for the request
    MaximumExecutionTime=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
    RetryPolicy=new ExponentialRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),3) //retry 3 times
});
```

Additionally, you could leverage `ListBlobsSegmented` to list blobs in pages. For more details, you could refer to List blobs in pages asynchronously section in this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs).